# Question about using a VISA card to withdraw money from PayPal balance

Tags: credit-card, online-payment, paypal, visa

According to the following PayPal policy,

https://cms.paypal.com/mz/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=ua/RecPymt_print

The only way for me to withdraw money from PayPal in my country is through a VISA credit card (It gets transferred at the start of each month for no fees).

But here is the part that is baffling me; I have never ever heard of someone depositing money into a credit card. I don't think credit cards support depositing money into to begin with.

So tell me, **what does it mean** that PayPal will transfer the money to my VISA card? Will it simply just get transferred to my bank account by the local bank after that?

I'm going to ask at the local bank, but I thought I'd get more opinions first. I appreciate your help. I'm relatively new to banking.

Comment: I think asking your card issuer would be more useful, as we can only guess.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think credit cards support depositing money into to begin with.

Anyone could deposit money to a Credit Card acccount.

All they need is your bank's name, Visa/Mastercard, and 16 digit number.

It is done through the "Pay Bills / Make Payments" function in online banking.

> So tell me, what does it mean that PayPal will transfer the money to my VISA card

You can use the new balance for spending via Credit Card, the effect is same as making a payment from your chequing account to credit card account.

> Will it simply just get transferred to my bank account by the local bank after that

Some banks would refund the excess amount from your Credit Card to your Chequing Account after a while, but most don't. People keep credit balance on credit card to make a purchaes larger than credit limit. For example, if your credit limit is $1000, balance is $0, and you made $500 payment to the credit card, you can make a purchase of $1500 without asking for credit limit increase.

Comment: "Anyone could deposit money to a Credit Card acccount." - most certainly not true.

Comment: Not true because of what? Restriction? No access to bank tellers or online banking?

Comment: Not true because it is not an option in many places. Don't assume that what works in your country works the same everywhere else.

Comment: Outside of that quibble, the rest of the answer seems accurate. (It is certainly possible for a store to issue a refund to a card, at least in the us and for the cards I'm familiar with. There may be restrictions on that which would keep it from being used for other kinds of credit; that will depend in part on the details of PayPal's specific agreements with the card processing systems and in part on what your bank has authorized or can authorize.)